# How do I stop elmah from using the email handler for local requests?

Tags: elmah

Can anyone suggest a quick way to tell Elmah not to use the email handler for local requests?

i.e. when `Request.IsLocal == true` I don't want to receive an email every time I generate an exception. Alternatively, a way to simply disable elmah altogether for local requests would be good.

I'd prefer an answer that doesn't require that I use a different Web.config locally than I use in production.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can configure [error filtering](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/ErrorFiltering) in ELMAH and express conditions for when an exception should be filtered/excluded from logging and/or mailing. The following error filter should help you to filter out exceptions (as far as ELMAH is concerned) occurring on local requests:

```
<errorFilter>
    <test>
        <equal binding="Context.Request.IsLocal" 
               value="True" type="Boolean" />
    </test>
</errorFilter>
```

For more details, see the wiki on [Error Filtering](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/ErrorFiltering) and [examples](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/ErrorFilterExamples) on the [ELMAH project site](http://elmah.googlecode.com).